# alloc + init memory usage mechanism

Tags: objective-c, foundation

I am just curious to know when an object has made by `alloc`, and a piece of memory allocated to it, why `init` don't use that piece of memory and changes the address of object?

```
NSDate *t = nil;
NSLog(@"t = %p",t); // t = 0x0 

t = [NSDate alloc];
NSLog(@"t = %p",t); // t = 0x100107af0

t = [t init];
NSLog(@"t = %p",t); // t = 0x1001035a0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two-step initialization allows us to do these kinds of things (namely, substituting an instance of a class for another depending on the initializer called).  Class clusters all over Foundation and UIKit take advantage of this to return instances optimized for a particular use-case.  For example, `UIColor` itself is just an interface for its subclasses that implement color caching (all the named initializers like `+blackColor`), the RGB color space (`+colorWithRed:green:blue:alpha`), the black and white color space (`+colorWithWhite:alpha:`), `CIColor` compatibility, etc.  And so `NSDate` is too.  When you call `-init`, Apple has means and motive to return a different object that implements the same interface as `NSDate` as an optimization because you honestly shouldn't care what you get as long as it doesn't launch the missiles when you try to message it properly.

Comment: `NSDate` doesn't launch missiles? I'm abandoning Apple for Google!

Answer (score 1):

As of the latest iOS SDK, calling `[NSDate alloc]` always returns the same memory location. You can verify this behavior with the following code:

```
NSDate *date1, *date2;
date1 = [NSDate alloc];
NSLog(@"date1: %p", date1);
date1 = [date1 init];
NSLog(@"date1: %p", date1);
date2 = [NSDate alloc];
NSLog(@"date2: %p", date2);
date2 = [date2 init];
NSLog(@"date2: %p", date2);
```

I suspect that it has to do with the fact that `NSDate` is a [class cluster](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/ClassClusters/ClassClusters.html).

If the private subclasses of a class cluster have different storage requirements, it's impossible to know inside of `alloc` how much memory to allocate. One approach to solving this problem, and it appears this is the approach that Apple is using with `NSDate`, is to let the `init` and factory methods handle all the memory allocation, since those methods know what private subclass is actually going to be used.

At that point, all `alloc` is doing for you is allowing the user to preserve the `[[NSDate alloc] init]` pattern that's used for object creation everywhere in Objective-C. Since the memory location returned by `alloc` is always discarded, `alloc` may as well just return a fixed memory location, which is what it appears to be doing.